# Android Custom View not working when added dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml

I've looked all over and seems that I am doing things the same way as others, yet I can't seem to get it to work.

I've made an xml layout with multiple views on it - it looks fine in the preview and it looks fine when it's hardcoded in the main xml. I want to add it dynamically, multiple times, like a list.

The code I am using to show it is this:

```
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.ticketinformation, null);
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewLinearLayout);
            layout.addView(v, i);
```

And the xml I am trying to show is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="123 Fake Street, ON, N2J 2C6"
            android:id="@+id/tvAddress" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="20150010011"
                android:id="@+id/tvRequestNumber"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="May 25, 2015"
                android:id="@+id/tvExcavationDate"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So if anyone can help explain to me why this won't appear, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you overwritten all 3 constructors of your view?

Comment: If you did then you forgot to call `super()`

Comment: its actually added but ur not able to see..

Comment: I don't believe I've overwritten any constructors of my view -- where/ how would I do that? I didn't think I needed to since there is no class involved, just the xml?

Comment: post complete java code of the class and the xml file name too.

Comment: the xml file name is ticketinformation.xml, and that's all the code related to this. Is it not possible to just have a layout xml with multiple views in it and then just add it to the current layout?

Answer (score 0):

```
layout.invalidate();
```

are you tryed this? 
Or maybe your LinearLayout`s orientation is wrong direction.